# "Cannot read property 'filter' of null" (slightly idfferent to other solutions i've seen here)

Tags: javascript

So my task is. Given an array of integers.
Return an array, where the first element is the count of positives numbers and the second element is sum of negative numbers.
If the input array is empty or null, return an empty array.

I've seen some solution here for angular or react.
I get error "Cannot read property 'filter' of null"

My code :

```js
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
  let positiveNums = input.filter(number => number > 0);
  let negativeNums = input.filter(number => number < 0);

  let positiveCount = positiveNums.length;
  let negativeSum = negativeNums.reduce( (total, num) => {return total + num}  )

  let result = [positiveCount, negativeSum];


  return result;
}
```

Comment: The error just means that `input` is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you need is to check the input has a value ...

I have used an if statment to make sure its filled in . If its not the else statement will return an empty array

```js
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
  
//if statment to check that the input is set 
// checks its not null 
// checls if the array is numeric
if ((typeof input !== 'undefined') && ( input !== null ) && (!input.some(isNaN))){
  
  let positiveNums = input.filter(number => number > 0);
  let negativeNums = input.filter(number => number < 0);

  let positiveCount = positiveNums.length;
  let negativeSum = negativeNums.reduce( (total, num) => {return total + num}  )

  let result = [positiveCount, negativeSum];


  return result;
  } 
   else
  {
   let result =[];
   return result;
  }

}
let x = countPositivesSumNegatives([4,4,-14]);
console.log(x)
```

Comment: what if `input` is `null` - since the error message states `Cannot read property 'filter' of null` your answer would not help

Comment: Edited it  to reflect the handling of null as well

Comment: why not `if (input && input.filter)` :p that way you'll never get an error - e.g. if the function is called with a string or a boolean or a number or an object, the code will still throw :p

Comment: If a variable is never declared and you try to check for its existence, you’ll get an error. But the typeof operator is the only operator (to my knowledge) that gets around this

Comment: Updated to check the array is numeric